# Do user-defined functions in mysql add processing time above the code inside

Tags: mysql, optimization

I am using a simple user-defined function in mysql to update a column in a big table (600k rows). E.g.

```
UPDATE table1 SET foo=bar(foo);
```

Will this update run more slowly than if the function code were written explicitly into the update? I.e. does the user-defined function add overhead to processing time? Do you know roughly how much?

Answer (score 0):

It will run slightly more slowly, since there is a tiny additional call out to the function, but the function will be compiled and you should not see much difference between the call and the in-line version.

The specific difference will depend on a whole bunch of things so the best way to find out is to test it yourself.

Comment: I _am_ testing it now as I sit and wait for this update to finish! Wondering whether to kill it and start over.

Comment: For tests, a common strategy is usually to start small and build up. If you just start big, you don't really know how long to expect to wait.